# How do I make a persistent domain with virsh?

Tags: libvirt, rhel6, virsh

`virsh create somefile.xml` creates my machine just fine but when I shut the machine down the whole thing disappears. Machines I made with the virt-manager GUI are persistent (stick around after shutdown) and the xml file is derived from those virt-manager created machines.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `virsh define somefile.xml` and `virsh start domain-name`, doing this the VM will be persistent.
I can't check right now, but I think you can use `virsh define` on an already started VM and this will make it persistent.

Comment: I can confirm this works with a domain started with the 'create' command

Comment: The best tip  I read today

Answer (score 12):

If you don't have the xml for the running vm (eg. after transient migration), you can do

```
virsh dumpxml vm_name > vm_name.xml
virsh define vm_name.xml
```

To check:

```
virsh list --all --persistent
```

The VM should now be listed.
Or

```
virsh dominfo vm_name
```

There should be a line with 'Persistent:     yes'.